# Missing underline and blue color for anchor while using ItextSharp to generate Pdf file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

I am getting link in pdf but underline and blue color is missing for anchor tag using the same iTextSharp

citation column required hyperlink in Citation field. Citation string has anchor tag.

Please let me know how I can apply own formatting for anchor tag (Underline and Blue color)

```
 protected void GeneratePdfReport(DataTable RRDT)
{
   // DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT * FROM Employees where EmployeeId = " + ddlEmployees.SelectedItem.Value).Rows[0]; ;
   // DataRow dr = RRDT.Rows[0];

    try
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40f, 88f, 30f, 10f);
        Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            Phrase phrase = null;
            PdfPCell cell = null;
            PdfPTable table = null;
            Color color = null;

            document.Open();

            //Header Table
            table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.TotalWidth = 500f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            //    table.SetWidths(new float[] { 1f });
            table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

            string TempCollege = "";
            string TempDepartment = "";
            string TempPublication = "";



            foreach (DataRow dr in RRDT.Rows)
            {

                if (dr["College"].ToString() != TempCollege || TempCollege == "")
                {

                //Citation
                phrase = new Phrase();
                phrase.Add(new Chunk(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dr["Citation"].ToString()) + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
                cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
                cell.PaddingBottom = 3f;
                cell.PaddingTop = 3f;

                table.AddCell(cell);
            }

            document.Add(table);

            document.Close();


                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ResearchReport.pdf");
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 
                HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
    {
        String errorString = "Something went wrong:";
        UCSparkCommon.SendExceptionEmail(errorString, ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String errorString = "Something went wrong:";
        UCSparkCommon.SendExceptionEmail(errorString, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any code to go with that problem? We cannot see what's on your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stated [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/84/itextsharp-links-and-bookmarks) that itext anchors are not styled by default (color/underline). You will have to apply your own styling.

And they shouldn't be, since they are not necessarily hyperlinks.

Hope it helps.